# C# Win Forms Background Animation

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, background

i want to make a window with animated background using the paint event.
Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace DrawGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            int w = this.ClientSize.Width;
            int h = this.ClientSize.Height;

            g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, h / 2 - 20, w, h / 2 - 20);

            int a = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                a++;
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, a, h / 2 - 20, 40, 40);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, a, h / 2 - 20, 40, 40);
                Thread
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine, but I can´t do anything else. How do I run the paint event in the background?

Comment: Of course you can't do anything else, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: You need to get a book on basic animation techniques.  This is not really a forum for fundamental tutorials of this type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run the `Paint` event in the background.  It is always fired on the GUI thread, and attempting to do drawing from a background thread would result in cross-thread errors anyway.  It's illegal to modify a `Control` from a background thread.

What you want to do instead of your while loop inside the `Paint` event handler is to set up a `Timer` that fires as frequently as you want to update the display, and in that timer's `Tick` handler call `Invalidate()`.  Then in your `Paint` event handler, keep track of what iteration you're on via a field on the `Control` and draw accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I´m gonna try that